# is there any possibility to display image from public folder in Laravel controller?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

this function returns only one image. but I want to show all images which are stored in this folder. can anyone help me?

**My controller**

```
    public function index()
    {
      $get=Resturant::all(['id','name','image']);

      foreach ($get as $image) {
        $path =public_path().'/Images/Resturants/'.$image->image;
        $file= File::get($path);
        $type= File::mimeType($path);
        $response= Response::make($file, 200);
        $response->header("Content-Type",$type);

        return $response;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Remove return form loop and change responses to the array. then try

Comment: i did. but same issue.

Comment: You can use the image directly on blade  file like this :
<img src="{{url('/images/myimage.jpg')}}" alt="Image"/>, <img src="{{ asset('images/a.jpg') }}" /> why are you doing that much mess. could you please explain more

Comment: there is no blade file coz I'm developing a rest api

Comment: these files are in your public folder, just return an array of URLs to these images, let the client make the requests to get those images from the web server

Comment: simply return image URLs and left other things on API consumers.

Comment: public function index()
        {
          $get=Resturant::all(['id','name','image']);
    $paths = array();
          foreach ($get as $image) {
            $paths[$image->id] = public_path().'/Images/Resturants/'.$image->image;
           return response()->json($paths);
          }
        }

Comment: "Tanawal": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\user\\public\\Images/Resturants/1610613985.jpg", its showing like this now how front-end developer will see image?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to be trying to return a file response, since your web server itself can handle serving files in the `public` folder. Also you wouldn't be trying to return multiple files (somehow) in the response. You can just return an array of the URLs to the files and let what ever is consuming this make the requests to get these files by URL. This would simplify your controller method quite a bit:

```
return Resturant::pluck('image')
    ->map(fn ($i) => asset('Images/Resturants/'. $i));
```

PHP 8 here, but its pretty simple, just have to make URLs from each image.

If you want to have the names to go along with this you can adjust `pluck` to use a column for the index:

```
...pluck('image', 'name')...
```

Comment: I did try. but it returns the only image name. Not a display image.

Comment: it isn't going to return an image, just the URLs ... that is the point, you have no need to try and return a file response from the controller as the webserver is built to serve files already

Comment: "Tanawal": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\user\\public\\Images/Resturants/1610613985.jpg",
its showing like this now how front-end developer will see image?

Comment: @fahadaslam updated, used the wrong function, sorry about that

Comment: adjust your code to match what is in the answer now, just changed `public_path` to `asset`